# Appropriate InputOutput

Tags: java, io

Good day, i'm stuck figuring out correct way to implement a function, the function has the following functionality.

**1.** When program starts, text is displayed to enter a key or leave field empty.

**2.** If text was entered , do A.

**3.** If text wasn't entered do B.

This is what i've done so far.

```
System.out.println("Enter any key to get data or leave empty");
//Just give some value
int value = 0;
try {
    for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("Starting in " + i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //If enter was pressed then theoretically value
        //should be 1(Not working)
        value = System.in.read();
    }
    if (value != 0) {
        Database.getInstance().getAllStamps();
    } else {
        start();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why would `value` be `1` in that case?

Comment: `System.in.read()` returns the byte of data read, not a success flag.

Comment: I guess line `value = System.in.read();` should be outside of `for` loop. And if user presses enter without any input the `value` is `10` which is new line.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
     System.out.println("Starting in " + i); 
     Thread.sleep(1000);     // Execution pauses
     if(sc.hasNext())
          // call your function
          break;
     }
 }
```

or

```
boolean flag = false;
for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
     System.out.println("Starting in " + i); 
     Thread.sleep(1000);     // Execution pauses
     if(sc.hasNext())
         flag = true;

     }
 }
 if(flag) { 
 // call your function 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get raw input is to use a [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Use something like this:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
if(sc.hasNext()){
    //do stuff with input
}
else{
    //handle stuff
}
```